# What is there to do on a Heroku staging app?

Tags: heroku, staging

I understand how to create and deploy code to a staging environment on Heroku before deploying it to production. I understand that it is good to see if the code will "blow up" in a very similar environment than the one in production.

However, I can't figure out any tangible ways or mechanisms to determine if the application is broken on the staging environment.

In other words, I don't understand how having a running application on the staging environment is supposed to give me the confidence to deploy my application to production.

Hence my questions:

1. What additional steps are there to do on the staging environment on Heroku?
2. Are the integration tests supposed to be run on the staging environment?
3. If I note that the application is running on the staging environment, is it good enough?

Answer (score 0):

A staging environment is intended just for that - to stage, or to "rehearse" an app version, before you promote it to production.

Heroku pipelines enable you to deploy a staging app in an environment as identical as possible to your production app, to reduce "but it worked in my dev environment" problems.

What you do with your app on the staging environment is up to you.  You can consider using various simulation tools to simulate live users who would be accessing your production app. You might have migrations that you need to perform on your production app's data, so you could run them first in your staging app. You can have testers working with your staging app to verify everything works as intended before promoting to production.

Bottom line: Whatever you can do with your production app, you should be able to do with your staging app. Therefore, you should strive to achieve a deployment flow whereby BEFORE promoting a version to production,  whatever scenarios may occur on production should first be tested on staging. How you achieve that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

**What additional steps are there to do on the staging environment on Heroku?**

1. Visually catch any broken CSS + HTML (which is a very difficult task with currently testing tools)
2. You might have other members in your team (SEO specialist, Marketing Manager, etc) which wants to inspect text, meta tags, etc. Having a staging environment will just make their life much easier as they can navigate and probe, propose improvements, etc
3. In your development machine you and other team members may have a different environment than you have running on production (different DB OS versions and third party services (.i.e Elasticsearch, Redis, etc) just to name a few.
4. You want to test deployment itself (you might have a series of tasks that are triggered during deployment)

   The list of benefits and advantages of having a staging environment as close as possible as your production environment goes on...

**Are the integration tests supposed to be run on the staging environment?**

Normally you run your automated tests in a CI server (not on staging). Staging is just there to visually test and maybe to catch an error not covered yet by your test scenarios

**If I note that the application is running on the staging environment, is it good enough?**

Good enough is difficult to say (your staging environment may not be a perfect copy of your production environment), but if it is well tested, it should be very close to what you expect to see running in production

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it looks like the staging environment is helpful for manual testing.
In a context of Continuous Delivery, the staging environment can't help much with automatically deploy into production, no? Can I set up some sort of automatic verifications in the staging environment that, if successful, would trigger a production deployment?

Comment: Would you risk going to production with CSS broken for example ? This may not appear in your tests, but has a HUGE impact for end users

Comment: Of course not. Then, is there a way to automatically test stuff in the staging environment to catch various problems, e.g. a broken CSS file?

Comment: To my knowledge there is not yet a really efficient way to test for broken stylesheets. And if there is, I would really like to know =). Your CSS may be consistent, but visually it appears broken in the website.